# Is there such a thing as a paired-samples F-test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, variance, paired-data, f-test

I have paired data (from a pre/post-test) for which I assume that the variance differs between groups (again between pre/post). Visually, this assumption appears to check out and there is less variance in the post-test group than there is in the pre-test group. How would I go about constructing a statistical test for this?

If the samples were independent, a F-test would seem like the most appropriate choice. However, - if I understand correctly - it assumes that samples are drawn independently, which is not the case for me (since they are paired). Another thought I had was along the lines of using Mauchly's test, but that is for sphericity and only makes sense for 3+ levels of repeated measures.

I guess what I'm really asking is: Is there a paired-samples F-test (and who is it named after so that I can find it and read up on it :D).

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to do this for the mean, the natural place to do would be the paired t-test. Despite there being two groups, the paired t-test is a one-sample test. That sample is composed of the pairwise differences between the two paired samples, such as subject 1 after minus subject 1 before, subject 2 after minus subject 2 before, etc. As scientists, we know how that once sample was created and use that to guide the interpretation, but the math does not care that the numbers came from pairwise differences.

Consequently, you are not doing a two-sample test, and a two-sample variance F-test does not make sense. If you have some sense of what the variance of the paired differences should be under a null hypothesis, you could do a one-sample variance test on the paired differences. However, I do not see a default null hypothesis like in the case of means where it makes sense to assume there is no difference ($\mu=0$) under the null hypothesis. The variance of the pairwise differences could be four or ten or seven of a billion, depending on the circumstances.

[As usual, the JBStatistic YouTube channel has a nice video on one-sample variance testing.](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=PweabcpqzYI)